# dynamic variables in preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text template like this:

```
$template = [FIRSTNAME] say hello to [NAME]
```

I have an user array like

```
[user_name] => myname
[user_firstname] => myfirstname
```

and I would like to transform it with `preg_replace` so I tried this:

```
$replacement = '$user[user_${1}]';
$result['texte'] = preg_replace('/[(.*)]/', {$replacement}, $result['texte']);
```

without any success :(

Comment: Have a look at `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: also, you'll need to escape the square brackets in your regex. otherwise you'll match only one character out of `(`, `.`, `*`, `)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/[(.*)]/` does not escape the `[` or `]`, and would match essentially *everything* if it did.  Use `/\[(.*?)\]/`.  Additionally, you need to `strtolower` the matched inner value.

```
$template = "[FIRSTNAME] say hello to [NAME]";
$replacements = array(
   'user_name' => 'myname',
   'user_firstname' => 'myfirstname',
);

$result['texte'] = preg_replace_callback('/\[(.*?)\]/', function ($match)
    use ($replacements) {
    return $replacements["user_" . strtolower($match[1])];
}, $template)
```

Comment: Works very well ! Thanks for the tips about regex and []