# Adding id an attribute to paragraph elements

Tags: php

Suppose that a variable contains html markups like below:

```
<p> paragraph 1 </p>
<p> paragraph 2 </p>
...
```

How can I turn it to something like this:

```
<p id="1" data-pic="someStaticText"> paragraph 1 </p>
<p id="2" data-pic="someStaticText"> paragraph 2 </p>
...
```

Of course, it's not just composed of paragraph elements.

Comment: You need a html dom paser. Try xpath or SimpleHtmlDom.

Comment: @silentboy: what do you mean by "Try xpath" ?

Comment: @zerkms, the meaning is as clear as do not try spamming

Comment: @silentboy: excuse me? I asked because your last phrase doesn't make much sense, and I wanted to clarify it.

Comment: @zerkims, it's ok. Using xpath or SimpleHtmlDom the job is not very hard. So I asked him if he dare to work with them

Comment: @silentboy: `xpath` is not a parsing library. You cannot say "try xpath or simplehtmldom", they are incomparable. But you could say "Try DOM or SimpleXML"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out while doing [some more research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309241/1778592):

```
$html_string = preg_replace_callback(
    "(<p(.*?)>)is",
    function($m) {
        static $id = 0;
        $id++;
        return "<p id=\"p".$id."\"data-pic=\"someStaticText\"".$m[1].">";
    },
$html_string);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a while loop with each iteration replacing the first <p> of the string.

```
$id = 1;
while(strpos($html_string, '<p>') !== FALSE){
    $html_string = str_replace('<p>','<p id="'.$id.'" data-pic="someStaticText">',$html_string, 1);
    $id++;
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in ... line 3`

Comment: Also, in `FALSE))`, the second parenthesis should be removed.